# Get the name of a factory function when passed with parameters (weird)

Tags: javascript, callback, factory-pattern

Okay, so I have a problem.

**SHORT VERSION:** 
I want to do this:

```
const createThing = function( behaviours(intensities) ){
    return {
       behaviour1: behaviour1(intensity1),
       behaviour2: behaviour2(intensity2)
       and so on for each behaviour(intensity) passed as an argument
    }
}

//so when doing:

const wtf = createThing( cat(loud), dog(whereistheball), bird(dee) );

// wtf should be:

{
   cat: cat(loud),
   dog: dog(whereistheball),
   bird: bird(dee)
}
```

I've tryied among other things something like this:

```
const createThing = function( behaviours(intensities) ){
        return {
           for(a in arguments){
              [a.name]: a; 
           }
        }
    }
```

I've been trying a lot of different ways to do this on the past week with no success. Can anyone help me?

**LONG VERSION:** 
Okay so I have a magnet behaviour factory function and a particle factory function, it looks like this

```
const magnet = funtion(intensity) {
   // returns a magnetic object with that intensity
}

const createParticle = function( location, static or dynamic, behaviours ){
  // returns a particle object with the properties and behaviours listed above
}
```

The problem is I can't get the behaviours part to work. By now I have a magnetic behaviour factory, but I also want to have an eletrical, gravitacional, random etc. I want the particle object to get the behavior name as a new property key and the object it creates as this property value when this behaviour is passed as an argument to the particle factory function, something like this:

```
const particle1 = createParticle ( location, dynamic, magnet(intensity) )

//should return
{
   location,
   dynamic,
   magnet: magnet(intensity)
}
```

or even

```
const particle2 = createParticle ( location, dynamic, magnet(intensity), eletric(intensity) )

//should return
{
   location,
   dynamic,
   magnet: magnet(intensity),
   eletric: eletric(intensity)
}
```

and so on.

I tried using the method function.name, but it is not possible since when I pass the behaviour function as a parameter to the particle, it evaluates into an object. I tried using a callback function and then using function.name but it doesn't do anything since I still need to pass the behavior function along with its parameters to the particle factory.

Is it even possible??? How???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Not unless `cat`/`dog`/`bird`/`magnet`/`eletric` all return an object that contains the name of the respective factory.

In particular:

```
function createParticle(...args) {
    const particle = { kind: 'particle' };
    for (const element of args)
        particle[element.kind] = element;
    return particle;
}
```

If you are using classes/constructors+prototypes, you can of course use the implicit `.constructor.name` instead of the `.kind` property that I chose in the example above.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved it!
Now I'm on a new adventure exploring solutions on how to get the particle location inside the magnet (because theres a field(x,y,z) method in the magnet wich calculates the field it produces somewhere in space, and that function needs the magnet position, wich is the particle position - that needs to change dynamicly as the particle moves), but theres  tons of discussions around this, I'm reading.

Comment: Solved that one as well, if someone wants to see the full code in development, here: [link](https://github.com/danielx-art/particlePhysics/blob/master/physics.js)